# Greyed-Out Documents in Document Picker - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am using `react-native-document-picker` and cannot get the images to be selectable. They are always greyed out.

```
const file = await DocumentPicker.pick({
   type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles]
});
```

I've even tried adding the specific file formats that I'm trying to select. I've also tried removing the `type` param from the config. Nothing has worked.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to the react-native-document-picker team, this appears to be an iOS 15 simulator issue. I have tested it on iOS 14 simulator and it works.

Others have pointed out that real devices work fine.

Here is the thread on GitHub: https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker/issues/532